# React.js unable to display last 5 data fields

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to display the last 5 repos of a GitHub user. However i am only able to either display all repos of user or none at all. I am not sure where I am doing wrong.
Edited to use array slice instead of for loop

```
import React,{Component} from "react";
import withRouter from "../withRouter";
class Repose extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={ repos: []};
        
    }
    async componentDidMount(){
        const FetchRepose = async(user)=>{
            const API_Call=await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${this.props.user}/repos`)
            const data= await API_Call.json();
            return {data}
        }
        FetchRepose(this.props.user).then((res)=>{
            if(res.data.length>0&!res.data.message){
                let items =res.data;// Displays all repos. If items=[] will display empty field
                this.setState({repos:items[items.length-5][items.length]});
            }
        })

    }
Data(){
        return(
        <div>
        <div>
          <h3>here Last 5 repo</h3>
            <div className="lastfiveRepo">{this.props.user}
              {this.state.repos.map(res=>(
                  <div key={res.id}>
                      <a key={res.id} href={res.html_url}>
                          {res.name}
                          
                      </a>
                  </div>
              ))}
           
            </div>
          </div>

      </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `last 5`? How should the repos be sorted?

Comment: You could just slice the last 5 items : data.slice((data.length-5)) and set that to the state

Comment: Sorting repos so the latest 5 post by user will be shown. Instead of showing all the repos by user

Comment: @genebent do you still need help with this question?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to do any sorting, ordering or limiting, you should [use the API's capabilities to do that](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos#list-repositories-for-a-user) for you.

You can request a sort, order and limit of the results with the `sortstring`, `direction` and `per_page` parameters e.g.

`https://api.github.com/users/${this.props.user}/repos?sortstring=created&direction=desc&per_page=5`

This will return the latest 5 created repos by user without any data manipulation required in the component.

```
class Repose extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { repos: [] };
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    const res = await fetchReposByUser(this.props.user);
    if (!res.data.message) {
      this.setState({ repos: res.data });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.repos.map((repo) => (
          <li>
            <a href={repo.html_url}>{repo.name}</a>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

const fetchReposByUser = async (user) => {
  const API_Call = await fetch(
    `https://api.github.com/users/${user}/repos?sortstring=created&direction=desc&per_page=5`
  );
  const data = await API_Call.json();
  return { data };
};
```

[image: Edit pedantic-cache-rygtqz]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using for loop, better use [array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to extract slice of the data you need.

Replace the following code snippet...

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  if (i === 4) {
    this.setState({ repos: items });
  }
}
```

with this...

```
this.setState({ repos: items[items.length - 5: items.length] });
```

Then do the rendering of the `repos` inside the `render` method.

Comment: Hi i am getting this.state.repos is undefined error

`{this.state.repos.map(res=>(
                  <div key={res.id}>
                      <a key={res.id} href={res.html_url}>
                          {res.name}
`